# Server does not have Digest::SHA 'hmac_sha256_base64' installed, can I use Digest::HMAC_SHA1 'hmac_sha1' instead?

Tags: perl, cgi

I am preparing a CGI script that needs to confirm that the body of a incoming post request message, when is converted into a HMAC-SHA256 hash, is exactly the same content that also comes in a header tag of the same incoming message.

I have been able to confirm using Python that the procedure is as explained above, but when I do the same functionality on a CGI script I cannot match the contents and probably is because I am not using the correct encryption / hashing library.

My server provider does not have the Digest::SHA library and thus, I can not use the 'hmac_sha256_base64' function. I cannot ask them to install it, I just can use what is already available.

I have checked the available libraries and there is a Digest::HMAC_SHA1 'hmac_sha1' library / function. So I am doing as follows:

```
my $q = CGI->new;
my %headers = map { $_ => $q->http($_) } $q->http();

# below is the secret key, is an example but I am using the good one
my $channel_secret="abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd" 

# Incoming request body string
my $httpRequestBody = $q->param( 'POSTDATA' ); 

# now, I want to use Digest::SHA hmac_sha256_base64 but this server
# does not have it so I am using the following one... 
# because I thought it was the equivalent new function to do the same
# but probably it is not...
use Digest::HMAC_SHA1 'hmac_sha1';
use MIME::Base64 'encode_base64';

$digest = hmac_sha1($httpRequestBody, $channel_secret);
my $signature = encode_base64($digest);
```

So basically I expect that these two variables contain the same string:

```
$headers{'A_EXISTING_TAG_OF_THE_HEADER'} 
$signature
```

But they are totally different. I suspect that I am not using the correct algorithm.

> So my question is:
>
> If my server provider does not include Digest::SHA 'hmac_sha256_base64' in the available libraries, then what other alternatives do I have to make the same? Is Digest::HMAC_SHA1 'hmac_sha1' the same functionality or not?

Comment: SHA1 and SHA256 are not the same,but Digest::SHA contains everything you need, https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA

Comment: @Pradeep that would be great if my server had the Digest::SHA library, but it is not installed as I mention in the question, neither I can ask to be installed, so I need an alternative (if any)

Comment: you can copy https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA::PurePerl no build/compile required

Comment: @Pradeep thanks, my doubt is copy where? I just have access to the place where I put my scripts, I cannot copy anything to the perl folders (I am not admin), so I just copy it to the same folder where I have my scripts and call it?

Comment: Digest::SHA is a core module, so if it is not installed, you should request that a full Perl be installed.

Comment: @Grinnz I guessed so... then I am lost because that is exactly what I cannot do. It is a very old fashion service provider with strong restrictions. In the past for different reasons we also required something else in the server and the answer was no. Time to change of provider...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the tarball for Digest::SHA::PurePerl ( you'll find the download link on this page https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA::PurePerl )

Create a library folder, something like this

```
.
|-- library
|   `-- Digest
|       `-- SHA
|           `-- PurePerl.pm
`-- your_script.pl
```

your_script.pl looks like this, you can implement similarly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use lib '.';
use lib '/tmp/iadvd/library/';

use Digest::SHA::PurePerl qw(sha1 sha1_hex);

print sha1_hex('Pradeep'),"\n";
```

Comment: Please don't recommend using an unpacked CPAN tarball directly as code. Only fatpacked scripts can be used this way reliably. Instead one should use local::lib to install it locally (most simply with `cpanm -l local Digest::SHA::PurePerl`), or [fatpack](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) the dependency yourself.

Comment: @Grinnz that is fine if you can access to your account and run code but I just can access to put script files via ftp and modify permissions of files, that is all. So I need (if possible) an alternative existing library or method.

Comment: @Pradeep your solution worked like a charm. Probably as Grinnz says is not the safest or cleanest but given the strong restrictions I have in my server this has saved my day for my following tests. Thank you very much!

Comment: @iadvd Everything I said only requires copying files to the target server, as long as the modules are pure perl (which it is).

Comment: @Grinzz ok, sorry by your explanation I thought that it was required to use cpanm or fatpack via command line.